# Google sign-in blocked by Google

Tags: google-account

I received an email from Google last night at 4:46am saying:

> Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account, using an application such as an email client or mobile device.

It's not phishing, since I got a similar notification from the Google app on my Android devices.

I logged in to look for more details, but all Google showed was an unknown device, in the US (my location), with an IPv6 of 2607:f8b0:400d:c04:0:0:0:216.

I did a [reverse lookup](http://tools.tracemyip.org/lookup/2607%3Af8b0%3A400d%3Ac04%3A%3A216), and it seems that this IP resolves to Gmail. It does makes sense that the Gmail app on one of my devices would try to sync at that time.

I can enable 2-factor authentication, but why is Google blocking its own server?

Comment: It looks like the address could have been spoofed.